# How to send a custom error message in rust-warp?

Tags: rust

I use warp(0.3.2) to handle a couple of routes (POST /topup and POST /print):

```
// main.rs
let print_route = warp::path("print")
    .and(warp::path::param::<String>())
    .and(warp::post())
    .and_then(handle_upload);

let topup_route = warp::path("topup")
    .and(warp::post())
    .and(warp::body::json())
    .and_then(handle_topup);

let routes = root
    .or(print_route)
    .or(topup_route)
    .recover(handle_rejection)
    .with(warp::cors().allow_any_origin());

println!("Client is up and running at localhost:{}", PORT);
warp::serve(routes).run(([0, 0, 0, 0], PORT)).await;
```

on both `handle_upload` and `handle_topup` functions, I use a custom error type `AppErr`

```
use warp::{reject::Reject};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AppErr {
    pub reason: String,
}

impl Reject for AppErr {}
```

If I need to throw an error on any part of the `handle_topup` or `handle_upload`, I just call the `warp::reject::custom()` function like this:

```
let reason = format!("Error writing file to destination: {}", &path);
warp::reject::custom(AppErr { reason })
```

Every `reason` that I give should be forwarded to client, so I just make a `handle_rejection`  to convert any `AppErr` from both routes into a response type that will be sent by warp

```
// Custom rejection handler that maps rejections into responses.
async fn handle_rejection(err: Rejection) -> Result<impl Reply, std::convert::Infallible> {
    if err.is_not_found() {
        Ok(reply::with_status("NOT_FOUND", StatusCode::NOT_FOUND))
    } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<AppErr>() {
        Ok(reply::with_status(e.reason.as_str(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))
    } else {
        eprintln!("unhandled rejection: {:?}", err);
        Ok(reply::with_status(
            "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        ))
    }
}
```

It should be easy enough, but I have a problem with this line

```
error[E0597]: `err` does not live long enough
   --> src\main.rs:225:29
    |
225 |     } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<AppErr>() {
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                             |
    |                             borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                             argument requires that `err` is borrowed for `'static`
...
234 | }
    | - `err` dropped here while still borrowed
```

If it try to clone the `e.reason` it throws `temporary value dropped while borrowed` error.
My question is why I can't make anything from `e` available to outside scope of `if let Some(e) = err.find::<AppErr>()`

Comment: How about you just take ownership of the reason? `Ok(reply::with_status(e.reason.as_str().to_string(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))`

Comment: Seems reasonable but it just can't be done. `expected &str, found struct std::string::String
 help: consider borrowing here: &e.reason.as_str().to_string()`

Comment: If I try to do that, then `error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed`

Comment: the problem is that your arms have different types. Check the update

Comment: OK that solves it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`err` cannot be borrowed after the scope of the function (since it is consumed by it).  Hence you need to take ownership of the parts you need:

```rust
async fn handle_rejection(err: Rejection) -> Result<impl Reply, std::convert::Infallible> {
    if err.is_not_found() {
        Ok(reply::with_status("NOT_FOUND".to_string(), StatusCode::NOT_FOUND))
    } else if let Some(e) = err.find::<AppErr>() {
        Ok(reply::with_status(e.reason.as_str().to_string(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))
    } else {
        eprintln!("unhandled rejection: {:?}", err);
        Ok(reply::with_status(
            "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR".to_string(),
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        ))
    }
}
```

`String` implements `Reply` (as well as `&str`), you can find more in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/reply/trait.Reply.html)

Your `if/else` branches would have different types (`&str` vs `String`), use `to_string` in all the branches, or you have to dynamically dispatch them with `Box<dyn Reply>` or maybe use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).